# Skype.getAllChats() not detecting cloud-based group chats

Tags: java, skype, skype4java

I'm trying to write a bot that, for starters, listens and logs every message said in a cloud-based chat -- that is, a chat where the command `\get name` returns a string with the prefix `19:`, e.g. `19:f0ddd8dbc5b64372a2dd1de9f37f8689@thread.skype` in my specific case.

However, I cannot get Skype4Java to find any of the cloud-based chats I'm participating in.

```
Group[] groups = Skype.getContactList().getAllGroups();
```

The above returns an empty list, even when there are P2P groups present.

```
Chat[] chats = Skype.getAllChats()
```

The above returns all chats (P2P group or individual) **except** for cloud-based group chat.

Is Skype4Java not able to interact with cloud-based chats? I know Skype4Py (the Python equivalent) isn't able to. (Inappropriate follow-up question: are there any APIs that *do* interact with cloud-based chats?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit: This is a self-answer after hours of mostly fruitless research. Putting it up in the hopes that it'll help some other newb bot writer.)

Skype4Java, Skype4Py, and most other API wrappers **cannot** interact with cloud-based chats.

There is no workaround other than recreating the desired chat with `/createmoderatedchat` and adding all the participants from the previous.

The only alternative I could find is [Skypeweb](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb), a library that's part of Skype4Pidgin. It does work with cloud-based chats, as far as I can tell. However, there is very little documentation.

[This article](https://wiki.bitlbee.org/HowtoSkypeWeb) from the Bitlbee Wiki may be helpful. It describes how to incorporate SkypeWeb into Bitlbee.